# RedHat Linux 7.0.2, error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, redhat

I have a simply java batch application that reads Oracle Database to generate text output file. It is started periodically (**each 5 min)** with cron job and runs with java 1.8 update 73 on Redhat 7.0.2 Enterprise Edition (64 bit).

There is a strange problem to get this error one time per day "**java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**", although in general it works.

Do you have any idea why it happens?

Best regards
Yuriy

Environment variables

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/prerap/bin:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_73/bin
export JAVA_PATH=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_73/bin/java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_73
```

======

```
 java -version
    java version "1.8.0_73"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16656/problem-to-launch-java-at-debian-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libjli - it seems related to the issue you experience.

Comment: It is different situation. The java application works well in general, but one time per day I got this error accidentally.